# How does XORing the A register clear the carry bit on the F register in the Z80?

Tags: assembly, xor, microprocessors, z80

I'm reading a book about the Zilog Z80 processor, in which whenever the author wants to clear the carry bit for a possible reason he does any of the following:

```
XOR A
AND A
OR  A
```

How does that affect the C bit which is in the F register? In other words, how does performing an operation on some register (A) affects another register (F)?

Comment: I still don't understand what you mean by "how". That's just how it works, by definition. It's not a weird thing hardware-wise either.

Comment: But it doesn't make sense to me or I just don't get it. I mean, when you `LD A, 0` it affects the A register, not the B register, not the F register, because that's the register I've chosen to perform the operation on. So why is `XOR  A` an exception?

Comment: _"how does performing an operation on some register (A) affects another register (F)"_. That's a common, and often desirable property. `F` is, after all, the _flags_ register. For example, after doing a `cp` you might want to know if the operands were equal (Z is set), and after an `add` you might want to know if a carry was generated, etc.

Comment: @Michael Oh, now that *"how it affects another register"* part seems logical, especially with the second example you gave. But in that example using `ADD` then affecting the C bit is the next logical thing to do in order to continue with the appropriate procedure in case of a carry/borrow, in other words there is a relation between A--for example--and F. While in the `XOR A` example it still doesn't make sense to me because there's still no relation between them, maybe it's just my unawareness of the hardware stuff.

Comment: @AbdelrahmanEid actually, there is a relationship between the Z80 ALU and the flag register - the flag register receives the flags from the ALU operation - not between a register and the flag register

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I understand your concern.  The flags register gets the result of an operation so it makes sense that AND, OR, XOR all affect the Zero flag, Sign flag and Parity flag.  Those are all direct properties of the result.  But the operations are not arithmetic so Carry isn't a natural property.

I think the answer lies in the ALU itself.  As programmers we view the ALU as a multi-function box.  You give it a value and an operation and it performs that operation on the accumulator setting flags as a byproduct.  Internally we suspect it has a separate circuit for each operation: add, subtract, and, or, xor.

In actual fact it is more like a multi-purpose function of each bit that can be modified to perform the desired operations.  At a high level we can see this with add vs add with carry.  Internally the only difference in those instructions is whether or not the carry flag is used in performing the add.  Similarly, subtract is nothing but adding the two's complement of the number.  So subtract only has some front-end change of an operand and uses the same add circuit.

Now consider how we do an addition on a single bit.  Ignoring the carry, notice that 0+0 = 0, 0+1 = 1+0 = 1 and 1+1 = 0.  And what about carry?  carry(0+0) = carry(0+1) = carry(1+0) = 0 and carry(1+1) = 1.

Recognize those functions?  The carry of two bits is their AND.  The result of the two bits added is their XOR.  If you extend this idea a bit more you can see how a simple circuit can add two bits together with a carry input and produce the resulting bit and a carry output.  Chain 8 of them together and you're adding numbers.

If you were designing a processor you might also notice that you can get XOR almost for free.  XOR is just adding two numbers together but stopping the carry going from bit to bit.  Similar shortcuts can pull the AND value out you normally get from the carry calculation and I'm sure there's some other trick to find OR in there.  The details get pretty important here because the designers of the Z-80 were not using AND and XOR gates but raw transistor logic which is even more flexible in what it can produce from a circuit.

Anyhow, now there's a choice.  Our XOR is zeroing the carry between each bit.  What about the 8th bit?  Well, offhand we should zero it as well.  Otherwise the carry bit will be the AND of the sign bits which just seems like it will confuse and annoy assembler programmers and not be of much use.  But if we zero that carry bit like we did all the others then we have a nice, symmetric circuit and the result is clear and unambiguous.  And, I suspect, it is easier to zero the value than it is to ignore it.

So, letting the zero carry come through saves us a few transistors.  And that side effect comes in handy in an operations like "OR A,A" or "AND A,A" which otherwise doesn't do a whole lot.  Now, the Z-80 inherited this behavior from the 8080 so it was really the 8080 designer's choice not the Z-80.  You can see they thought about it in the instruction set as they only gave us two operations to directly affect the carry: SCF - set carry flag to 1 and CCF - complement the carry flag.  They explicitly avoided giving us a "clear carry flag" since "OR A,A" already does that for free.  Thus the whole business saves an entire instruction.  And, we can only suppose, they reasoned that zeroing the carry flag on a logical operation isn't much of an impediment to programming.  In most cases you're either doing a logical calculation or an arithmetic one so logical operations zapping carry isn't a big deal.  Clearly other CPU designers didn't agree but it's a fair choice.

Bottom line: clearing the carry is a natural outcome of the circuitry which the 8080 designers decided was a useful side-effect to keep and chose to let it be rather than add circuitry to suppress it.

For specific detail, see how the [Z-80 ALU operates internally](http://www.righto.com/2013/09/the-z-80-has-4-bit-alu-heres-how-it.html) and the [8085 ALU internals](http://www.righto.com/2013/01/inside-alu-of-8085-microprocessor.html).

Comment: I would have thought it would take fewer transistors to build a separate boolean-logic unit than to disable/enable the carry propagation in a binary adder.  If it's a [carry-lookahead](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adder_(electronics)#Carry-lookahead_adder) adder, not just ripple-carry, that's several extra signals to disable.  Or can you gate them with a single transistor for each signal, without introducing an extra gate-delay into the normal operation of the adder?

Comment: I don't know enough about transistor-level construction to judge the choice of design.  I do know that the 6502 designers did choose to use separate logic for the ALU operations and simply select the desired result from all the outputs.  Indeed, had the Z-80 used (or needed) carry forwarding they might well have had to change their approach.

Comment: I should have just looked at your Z-80 ALU internals link, that seems to answer my question.  It shows the carry-out signal going through a NOR gate with the R control signal.  The auther also provided a transistor-level PDF but I'm not that curious to dig up the answer myself.  Doing an ADD with 2 passes through a 4-bit ALU shows just how cramped the transistor budget must be, compared to modern ALUs.  (e.g. pretty much every pipelined CPU does 32-bit ADD with 1 cycle latency.  Intel Sandybridge-family CPUs do 64-bit multiply with 3-cycle latency!)

Comment: Surely there is a typo in the fourth paragraph `0+0=1` should read `0+0=0`... no?

Answer (score 2):

Those 3 logical operations applied on the `A` register itself do not modify A (except for XOR which zeroes it).

But, as a side effect, all those instructions guarantee to clear the carry bit, as stated in the Z80 reference manual.

This side effect is the effect that's wanted here. `OR A` will do nothing else that clear C, and also affect other flags (depending on the initial value of A being zero or not, register Z is also set/cleared)

From [OR instruction description](http://z80-heaven.wikidot.com/instructions-set:or):

> Effects: C and N flags cleared, P/V detects parity, ...

Carry bit is set when an addition or a substraction overflows/underflows (ADD, SUB, ADC, SBC). You could clear C flags by performing an addition of zero + zero for instance, but that would require more instructions than `OR A`,`AND A` or `XOR A` making the latter more efficient.

Some other 8-bit processors like 6502 have specific CLC/SEC instructions to clear carry and do not need this side effect to do that.

Comment: My question is in the second line of your answer. How does that 'side effect' happen?

Comment: @AbdelrahmanEid what do you mean by "how" though? it just clears the flag

Comment: @harold Sorry if I'm not explaining well. See my edit please.

Answer (score 2):

The carry bit *per definitionem* is affected when an `add` or `subtract` instruction (or the like, `inc` and `dec` would fall into the same category) would borrow or carry over into the next higher bit "above" the register.

ALU-based commands that affect the flags (that is, most but the LD x,y and branch instructions) set or clear the C bit according to this "borrow" behavior. Pure logical (AND, OR, XOR) instructions have no borrow or carry behavior because they only affect the 8 bits in the register, and thus clear the carry flag.

EDIT: If you want to know "how that is done" - Because the CPU is built like that and the internal "wiring" forces the C bit to be the result of the logical over/underflow of the ALU after an operation. This is not a "side effect" as you seem to understand, but rather a very important one, because flags are the only way to base a logical decision (i.e. an "IF"-clause") on in Z80 assembly.

Comment: I do understand how/when the C bit is set, my question is: "How does performing an operation on a register (A) affects another register (F)?

Comment: Hmm. That I don't quite get, I'm afraid. Because the CPU is wired like that?

Comment: It's interesting that you say that you could not have "IF"-clause if the C flag wasn't cleared. The 6502 would not change the C flag on logical operations, it would affect Z so you would know whether the result was zero or not. But C was left alone.

Comment: @AlexisWilke Read again - The "No IF without flags" was related to all flags, not just C. For the XOR A instruction, it doesn't really matter whether C is affected or not. It is a design decision whether an instruction affects *all* flags or just some - I think *all* is easier to learn.

Answer (score 1):

Most processors are created using what we call microcode. One microcode instruction does one very small thing.

So we could show that the `OR A` instruction does something like this:

```
OR A     tmp ← A              modify register "tmp"
         tmp ← tmp | A        apply OR and save result in "tmp"
         A ← tmp              copy "tmp" back to A
         F[C] ← 0             clear C flag
         F[Z] ← A == 0        set Z to 1 if A == 0, zero otherwise
         F[N] ← A[7]          set N to sign bit of A
```

Note that since this has no effect on A, they could have renamed the instruction `CLC` (clear carry).

As mentioned by others, the clearing of the C flag was a choice that z80 designers decided on. Most processors do not affect the C flag on logical operation (AND, OR, XOR, NAND...)

Comment: That's not what microcode is.  I think you're mixing it up with micro-ops (i.e. the RISC-like internal operations that Intel CPUs decode x86 instructions into).  But even micro-ops aren't that small.  `add reg, reg` has always decoded to a single uop on all Intel CPUs, even Pentium 4.  Core2 and Sandybridge-family CPUs decode most common instructions to a single uop (unlike P4 where more instructions were multiple uops).

Comment: Those internal operations you describe *are* all things that the control circuitry has to do separately while decoding/executing the instruction, it's just that microcode or micro-ops are not the right name for them.  See [Agner Fog's microarch pdf and instruction tables](http://agner.org/optimize), and/or [David Kanter's Sandybridge writeup](http://www.realworldtech.com/sandy-bridge/) for more good stuff about CPU internals.